# Passing a value from a form to a report

Tags: c#, textbox, reportviewer

I have a form named "FormPay" and a textBox named txtAmount. Is it possible to pass the data from txtAmount to the textBox of my report?

I'm using c# report viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get data into your report is by passing in data via parameters, one you add a parameter to your report you can then use the following code to pass in a value.

ReportViewer.SetQueryParameter("ParameterName",txtAmount.Text);

There are a lot of options you can set/change, for example you can also hide the parameter if you don't want it visible on the report.

Comment: I tried this but there's an error. Wait, how can I add a parameter? or declare a parameter? because the error says that the parameter is not declared.

Comment: Have you declared the parameter in your report ?   Here is a link that tells how to do it, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337401.aspx.  Scroll down to "To add a new report parameter".